# Display image in wx.GridBagSizer

Tags: wxpython

I am trying to display an image on a wx.GridBagSizer

The image is being read and I can see it if I comment out the sizerMain.Add lines, but it will not show in the sizer. Interestingly the space is reserved for it in the sizer.

Can anyone please help?

```
    import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id,title):
      wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent, wx.ID_ANY, title, size = (1200,600), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.NO_FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE)

      sizerMain = wx.GridBagSizer(3, 2)
      self.sizerMain = sizerMain      

      pnl = wx.Panel(self)

      cmd1 = wx.Button(pnl, label='aaaaa')
      cmd2 = wx.Button(pnl, label='bbbbbb')
      cmd3 = wx.Button(pnl, label='ccccc')
      cmd4 = wx.Button(pnl, label='dddd')

      imgSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL) 
      image = wx.Bitmap('test.png',wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
      img = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, image)
      imgSizer.Add(img, flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)

      sizerMain.Add(imgSizer, pos=(0,0), span=(1, 3), flag=wx.TOP|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT, border=10)
      sizerMain.Add(cmd1, pos=(2,2), flag=wx.TOP|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT, border=10)
      sizerMain.Add(cmd2, pos=(1, 0), flag=wx.TOP|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT, border=10)
      sizerMain.Add(cmd3, pos=(1, 1), flag=wx.TOP|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT, border=10)
      sizerMain.Add(cmd4, pos=(2, 1), flag=wx.TOP|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT, border=10)
      pnl.SetSizer(sizerMain) 
      pnl.Layout()
      pnl.Fit()

      self.Show(True)

    def CloseWindow(self, event):
        self.Close()

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MainWindow(None, -1, "Test GridBag")
        frame.Centre()
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return True

# Declare the Application and start the Main Loop
app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Your code is working for me. Using Python279 with wxPython Phoenix (a build from last week).

Answer (score 0):

The parent of the wx.StaticBitmap "img" needs to be the panel "pnl". Not "self".